# Rayleigh quotient of a vector permutation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, permutations, spectral-theory, hermitian-matrices

The Rayleigh quotient of a Hermitian matrix $M$ and a complex vector $\mathbf{x}$ is defined as
$$R(M,\mathbf{x})=\frac{\mathbf{x}^HM\mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{x}^H\mathbf{x}},$$
which if $\lambda_\text{max}$ and
$\lambda_\text{min}$ denote the maximum and the minimum of the eigenvalues of $M$, respectively, then we have
$$\lambda_\text{min}\leq R(M,\mathbf{x})\leq\lambda_\text{max}.$$
My question is either of the following equivalent statements.
Let $P$ denotes a permutation matrix.

1. Given $R(M,\mathbf{x})=v$, does it imply that $R(M,P\mathbf{x})$ belongs to a **proper** subset of  $[\lambda_\text{min},\lambda_\text{max}]$?
2. Given $R(M,\mathbf{x})=v$, can $R(M,P\mathbf{x})$ assume any value in $[\lambda_\text{min},\lambda_\text{max}]$?
3. Is there any non-empty $S_v\subset[\lambda_\text{min},\lambda_\text{max}]$ such that $R(M,P\mathbf{x})\notin S_v$?
4. Is it true that $\left\{\Big(R(M,\mathbf{x}),R(M,P\mathbf{x})\Big):\mathbf{x}\in\mathbf{C}^n\right\}\neq [\lambda_\text{min},\lambda_\text{max}]\times[\lambda_\text{min},\lambda_\text{max}]$?

Example: Assume $M$ is diagonal. Then $R(M,\mathbf{x})\in\text{diag}(M)$ implies that for any permutation matrix $P$ we have $R(M,P\mathbf{x})\in\text{diag}(M)$; thus $S_v=[\lambda_\text{min},\lambda_\text{max}]\backslash\text{diag}(M)$.

Comment: There is not. Why do you suspect that there should be?

Comment: Because when I choose $R(M,\mathbf{x})$ and $R(M,P\mathbf{x})$ randomly in $[\lambda_\text{min},\lambda_\text{max}]$ my feasible set becomes empty most of the times.

Comment: That doesn't make sense: $\{R(M,P\mathbf x) : \mathbf x \in \Bbb C^n\}$ is necessarily equal to $\{R(M,\mathbf x) : \mathbf x \in \Bbb C^n\}$ because $\mathbf x \mapsto P\mathbf x$ is an invertible transformation.

Comment: Those sets are equal to each ther, but I suspect that given $R(M,\mathbf{x})$, $R(M,P\mathbf{x})$ assumes values in a proper subset of $\{R(M,\mathbf{x})~:~\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{C}^n\}=[\lambda_\text{min},\lambda_\text{max}]$.

Comment: I had somehow missed "if $R(M,\mathbf x) = v$ is given". Everything makes much more sense now

Comment: It is easy to come up with an example where there is no stricter bound: for example, if $M$ is diagonal and $\mathbf x$ is any of the standard basis vectors

Comment: But in the case that $M$ is diagonal, if $R(M,\mathbf{x})\in\text{diag}(M)$--which is actually the case when $\mathbf{x}$ is a standard basis vector--then we know that for any permutation matrix, $P$, we have $R(M,P\mathbf{x})\in\text{diag}(M)$. Thus, in this case, given $R(M,\mathbf{x})\in\text{diag}(M)$ restricts the feasible set of $R(M,P\mathbf{x})$ from the uncountable set $[\lambda_\text{min},\lambda_\text{max}]$ to the finite set $\text{diag}(M)$.

Comment: Sure, it is a much smaller set. If that is what you mean by finding a "stricter bound", then that's great but not the usual meaning of that phrase

Comment: So that said, it would be helpful if you could give a more precise indication of what exactly it is that you mean by a "bound", i.e. what kind of result you are looking for

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I edited the question

Comment: Your question is much clearer now. Unfortunately, I don't have anything like an answer. I have a hunch that a good place to start is this: if $v = \lambda_{\max}$, then what is the maximal value of $R(M, P \mathbf x)$ with $P \neq I$? Note that this depends on the specific eigenvalues: for the diagonal case with a non-repeating $\lambda_\max$, this maximum is the next largest eigenvalue. However if $\mathbf x = (1,\dots,1)$ is an eigenvector associated with $\lambda_{\max}$, then this maximum is $\lambda_{\max}$.

Comment: Are $x$ and $P$ fixed?

Comment: @user1551 We can assume $P$ is fixed and known. However, although the vector $\mathbf{x}$ is fixed, it is not known to us.